# Not able to automount NFS share

Tags: mount, nfs, automounting, autofs

I am using RHEL 6 and not able to mount NFS Share via automount . My Config files are as follows :-

```
#cat /etc/auto.master
/mnt auto.mnt

#cat /etc/auto.mnt
/nfsshare  -fstype=nfs,no_root_squash,rw,auto   172.XX.XXX.XXX:/root/shareit
```

I have restarted the autofs services a couple of times.  When i mount it using the mount command

```
#mount -t nfs -o rw,no_root,squash 172.XX.XXX.XXX:/root/shareit /mnt
```

i am able to successfully access my nfs share.

When i check `/var/log/messages` it shows `Sep 24 18:43:30 XXXX rpc.idmapd[2047]: dirscancb: open(/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs/nfs/clntXXX): No such file or directory`
Checking on google I found it is a [bug](https://rhn.redhat.com/errata/RHBA-2013-1301.html).

MY kerenl version is 2.6.32-358. Please let me know if i am doing any sought of mistake here. If not what will be the solution for the bug. Please note that this is not Production environment and i am practicing at home and i am not registered to Red Hat.

Comment: When you say "not registered to RedHat" is that as in "so i cant ask them for support" or "So i don't have any of the updates to the system.

Comment: When i checked the link it stated that i would have to update the nfs utils package . The repository which i am using is made from the ISO I downloaded from Internet. So in nut shell  to answear your query "i do not have any of the updates on the system" Moreover my main concern of posting this is to check if /not i have made any errors in the config files and also if it is bug in my case or not

Comment: your config doesn't jump out as wrong to me. Given your scenario, my honest recommendation would be to download `Centos` and repeat your task. `Centos` is identical to `RHEL` and doesn't require a contract to update, so you would eliminate patch related issues from your test.

Comment: try adding `vers=3` to your options

Comment: @steve Sorry that did not help :) . However i just made an observation that. When i do an ls -al /mnt it gives me total 4 but only shows . and .. in the output. Does that ring a bell ??

Comment: @RaghavChadha the 8 is a reference in KB as to how large the folder is, if you use `ls -lah` it will show you the size magnitude of the display, 8 is normal for an empty directory.